# connecting Azure Notebook to azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-notebooks

I am using Azure notebook. And I would like to connect a notebook to my private VM.

I Added the 8000 port to my VM network:
[image]

But when I try to connect my notebook to my VM (I am using the same account for both resources), I am getting this error:

```
There seems to be an issue connecting to the DSVM selected. Please check if you are able to connect to JupyterHub port at https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/ and retry.
```

[image]

I tried to connect using the link in the https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/ but I am getting "connection refused".

What am I doing wrong?